# How can I understand if there are threads in hang in the WebSphere Application Server

Tags: workload-scheduler

I'm using IBM Workload Scheduler (TWS) and when the product does not behave as expected or does not reply in a timely fashion, I am under the impression that there could be a thread hanging or blocked somewhere.
Is there a way to tell if there is a blocked thread?

Answer (score 1):

The first step to do is to check if in the SystemOut.log file of WebSphere Application Server (located in WAS_profile_path/logs/server1/SystemOut.log or WAS_profile_path\logs\server1\SystemOut.log in the master domain manager) there is any evidence that one or more threads are hanging. To do this, you can run the following command in the context of an UNIX shell:

cat WAS_profile_path/logs/server1/SystemOut*.log | grep hung

If this command returns something like:

root@MASTER:/opt/IBM/TWA/WAS/TWSProfile/logs/server1# cat SystemOut*.log | grep hung
[6/20/17 5:45:33:988 CEST] 000000b9 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WorkManager.ResourceAdvisorWorkManager : 0" (0000009e) has been active for 697451 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.

this might mean that a WebSphere thread could be hung. 
This may and may not be true, sometimes you have a thread that performs a lot of work and exceeds the set time limit (default value is 10 minutes).

In case you suspect that you are experiencing a real thread hung, consider to give a look to the following articles which provide detailed information to collect the data necessary to diagnose and resolve the issue:

- [WebSphere MustGather procedure on Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg21115785)
- [WebSphere MustGather procedure on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21111364)

A similar document exists also for AIX platform.